# Malfunctioning Poisson Fit Function on Python

Tags: python, statistics, poisson

I have trouble fitting a Poissonian distribution to my set of data. I have used this process to fit all my other data sets and it all turned out nicely, but for some reason, there's one set in particular that is not working.
My code goes this way:

```
E3_comb1=n.array([835., 822., 880., 876., 855., 866., 827., 903., 881., 850., 885.,
       811., 873., 887., 921., 948., 808., 938., 881., 845.])

plt.hist(E3_comb1, bins=140, edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Number of counts per bin')
plt.ylabel('Number of repetition')
plt.title('Amount of repetition of each number of counts per bin for Experiment 3, combined vertically')
```

Which outputs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GziZW.png) plot; which is what I expected.
Now, to compute my Poissonian fit, I have:

```
entries, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(E3_comb1, bins=140, range=[0, 950])
bin_middles = 0.5*(bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])
parameters, cov_matrix = curve_fit(poisson, bin_middles, entries)
```

Where my Poisson function is defined as:

```
def poisson(k, lamb):
    return (lamb**k/factorial(k)) * n.exp(-lamb)
```

Now, my values for entries, bin edges and bin middles are exactly what I expected them to be. But for some reason, it outputs a parameters' value of 0.19; ie, a mean of 0.19, when I would expect it to be around 880. Indeed, if I plot my Poisson fit, using:

```
plt.hist(E3_comb1, bins=140, edgecolor='black')
plt.plot(x, poisson(x, *parameters), '--r', label='poissonian fit')
plt.xlabel('Number of counts per bin')
plt.ylabel('Number of repetition')
plt.title('Amount of repetition of each number of counts per bin for Experiment 3, combined vertically')
plt.legend()
```

It outputs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyxvA.png), which is not what I wanted and clearly indicates something's going wrong. I tried to retrieve the error(s) but I cannot seem to be able to do so. I hope you will be able to tell me how to correct this.

As I am yet again a beginner at this, I also hope you can be as clear as possible.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: You can [estimate Poisson distribution parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Statistical_Inference) by simply taking the mean of the data.  Is there a reason that you don't do that?

Comment: Curve fitting, although it may seem like a natural thing to do, isn't the right way to go about this; since there is already a maximum likelihood estimator for this distribution, just use that. In this case the MLE is the mean of the data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect your Poisson distribution to have a center around 880. However, the `curve_fit` function will search for parameters with default values on the order of 1. This can be changed by adding a `p0=guess` argument to `curve_fit`, where `guess` is a tuple of all expected values of your `poisson` function. In your case just `lamb`.

Using your poisson function and some dummy arrays, we can see what shape we should expect by tweaking the `lamb` parameter:

```
x = n.arange(100)
plt.plot(x, poisson(x, 50))
plt.show()
```

A `lamb = 50` results in a distribution which is only 1e-16 tall in the y direction. Increasing `lamb` near 880 results in y which is under 1e-40 tall, so clearly this won't work. I would recommend playing with different values of `lamb`, plotting the resulting distribution, finding one that is close to what you expect, and using that `lamb` as a guess for the curve fit. Then your fitting would look something like this:

```
guess = (880)
parameters, cov_matrix = curve_fit(poisson, bin_middles, entries, p0=guess)
```

Due to the extremely small values you'll get from your `poisson` function when `lamb` is large, you may have to tweak your `poisson` function to add y or x scaling or offset.

Let me know if this helps any and I can look at it some more after you explore.

Comment: I am seemingly unable to fix the problem; the mean of the distribution remains around 0. Playing with the values of lamb do not help me much. To be honest, I am not entirely sure to understand everything. I hope you can enlighten me on this.